# Choice of font and layout for displaying text in more than one language at a time

Tags: fonts, layout

It is common to see bilingual books where the text is laid out side by side so that the reader is either reading in language A or language B but not looking at text in both languages at the same time. This means that the design and layout for each language does not affect the other. There are also similar questions previously regarding the [typesetting of bilingual books](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61204/good-strategies-for-typesetting-bilingual-books).

However, how does this apply in a digital sense, when you might actually have text in language A in one sentence, followed by the corresponding text in language B in the next sentence (which is typical for books with short sentences or content like children's books).

Comment: As far as I can understand; I would go with using Unicode fonts instead of usual font. As you might know that Unicode font comes with multi-lingual glyphs which resembles other language and contains same artistic feels. so even though language will change but font style will remain constant. ex. [Arial Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/arial-unicode-ms)!

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer when both texts use the Latin alphabet is to have one text in italics, so it has a different texture and stands out.

Answer (score 1):

You might proceed with both serif and sans-serif fonts, one for each language. There are hybrid fonts (having both serifed and non-serifed versions), such as Absara, Officina, Brioni, Rotis, Schnebel, Simplon, Alianza, Archivio, etc., which might suffice.